# Why do we have a written and reasoned judgment of Bower v Brewdog?

Tags: england-and-wales, civil-procedure, court, rules-of-court, court-records

I thought that in general, cases at the county court level are decided summarily, unless and until they get appealed to, e.g., the circuit judge.

Yet, [Bower v Brewdog](https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/Misc/2019/16.html) appears to have been judged by a district judge, in the county court, and I'm left wondering why.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing special, per se, about County Court cases being published. It's the content that matters, not the venue.

Bower v Brewdog has attracted some heightened media attention and public interest so, as a "notable" judgment, it was published presumably in line with [Incorporated Council of Law Reporting](https://www.iclr.co.uk/history/)'s selection criteria:

> - All cases which introduce, or appear to introduce, a new principle or a new rule.
> - All cases which materially modify an existing principle or rule.
> - All cases which settle, or materially tend to settle, a question upon which the law is doubtful.
> - All cases which for any reason are peculiarly instructive.

Comment: Okay so this addresses why the reasoned written judgment was published, but not why it was recorded and exists. Don’t most cases at gee county court DJ/DDJ level get decided summarily without a written statement of reasons?

Comment: Some do, some don't. Summary judgement just means there is not going to be a trial, and there are rules about what can (and cannot) be dealt with summarily.

Comment: Sorry I was using it in another perhaps incorrect sense and to mean, basically just a one liner ruling without a multipage written statement of reasoning.